# Apply EXIT_SAPFKCIM_001 user-exit before ALE conversion of IDoc?

Tags: abap, idoc

I have a basic IDoc type `ORDERS05` which goes through **ALE conversion rules**

My need is to get the data before the ALE conversion and modifying the IDoc.

I found the exit `EXIT_SAPFKCIM_001` / include `ZXKKCU01` where the data is still not converted,
the problem is that I was testing in the same system by simulating the send of the IDoc,
but now that I'm testing the real scenario (send the IDoc from system **A** to system **B**)
I receive the IDoc in system B with the ALE rules already applied but without the modifications applied in the exit.

I tried to put an infinite loop in the exit to debug, but it does not go through into it.

Could you help me identify the problem please?

Comment: `EXIT_SAPFKCIM_001` is called before the IDoc is created, maybe you tested on some IDocs created before the exit was implemented?

Comment: how do you create the idoc? some standard way (output, change pointers) or custom written module? how did you simulate the sending in the same system?